# How to set to the column list with the number of elements equal to the number of elements in the list on another column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How to set to the column list with the number of elements equal to the number of elements in the list on another column
Here is the df

```
t1     t2
[1,2]  NaN
[1]    NaN
[1,2,3]NaN
```

I want to get

```
t1     t2
[1,2]  [0,0]
[1]    [0]
[1,2,3][0,0,0]
```

Here is my code

```
df_1['t2'][df_1['t2'].isnull() & df_1['t1'].notnull()] = [0 for i in df_1['t1']]
```

But it somehow doesn't return lists, only integer number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```py
df['t2'] = df['t1'].apply(lambda x: [0]*len(x))
```

```
          t1         t2
0     [1, 2]     [0, 0]
1        [1]        [0]
2  [1, 2, 3]  [0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Assign mask to variable for each side of assignement and then use `apply` for replace values of lists (with mask for replace NaN if non NaN in `t1`):

```
import ast

#if possible strings repr of lists
#df_1['t1'] = df_1['t1'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

mask = df_1['t2'].isnull() & df_1['t1'].notnull()
df_1.loc[mask, 't2'] = df_1.loc[mask, 't1'].apply(lambda x: [0 for _ in x])

print (df_1)
          t1         t2
0     [1, 2]     [0, 0]
1        [1]        [0]
2  [1, 2, 3]  [0, 0, 0]
```

Alternative with `np.repeat`:

```
mask = df_1['t2'].isnull() & df_1['t1'].notnull()
df_1.loc[mask, 't2'] = df_1.loc[mask, 't1'].apply(lambda x: np.repeat(0, len(x)))

print (df_1)
          t1         t2
0     [1, 2]     [0, 0]
1        [1]        [0]
2  [1, 2, 3]  [0, 0, 0]
```